# Spring @scheduler vs. Quartz Scheduler which one is best

Tags: spring, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler

I got in to a task where we have to publish Metadata of one table to another application via REST web services.

Basically need is

- It has to be weekly scheduler and every week we push the data to
  them.
- Synchronous way.
- Job scheduler will kick up the job and call REST client.

I am thinking using spring batch scheduler as it is simple and not with Quartz scheduler. Let me know you view and perspectives.

Comment: Which one is "best" is very subjective? What is your definition of "best" ? You make your question more objective to get answers. You may want to research also e.g. https://dzone.com/articles/why-you-shouldnt-use-quartz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Quartz Job and Scheduling Tasks with Spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564101/difference-between-quartz-job-and-scheduling-tasks-with-spring)